# executing curl cmd in php should return json but instead returns array

Tags: php, json, curl

Just wondering if there is a setting that I am missing in my curl command that is preventing the data from coming back as a json string and instead returning it as an array.

```
 $cmd='curl -d @/home/wazilly/public_html/recipe.json -H "Content-Type: 
application/json" "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-details?
app_id=XXXXX&app_key=97d3b48d3a8366572c8012a142e28f50"';
exec($cmd,$result);
echo $result; //prints Array
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), `exec` always takes an array as its second parameter, which it fills with all the lines of output of the executed command.

I'm not certain what the output of your command would be like, though. You'd be better off doing a `var_dump()` on the `$result` to be certain. But since you're dealing with curl, why not simply use the [PHP curl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ?

Comment: Ah yeah I converted it php curl and was getting issue from server

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-details?app_id=XXXX&app_key=97d3b48d3a8366572c8012a142e28f50'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
    "file" => "@" .realpath("/home/wazilly/public_html/recipe.json")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} curl_close ($ch);

Answer (score 0):

Check the prototype for exec() in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

PHP returns an array.  If you want the raw output instead, which I assume might actually be JSON, try this instead:

```
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $result;
```

Comment: didn't have display_errors = on set in php.ini so had an error that i wasn't seeing. Once I fixed the error shell_exec($cmd) ran fine and returned string to $result. thanks. it's good to know that exec($cmd, $output) returns output as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you convert $result array to JSON format using `json_encode(array())`

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: yeah def. I just got hung up on the curl command exec. Weird thing is I'm still not sure why the php curl library code that I used returned an error from apache...I contacted edamam.com but you have to pay for tech help so prob no dice...this is the code. says server can't handle the request or something.

Comment: $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "api.edamam.com/api/…); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $post = array( "file" => "@" .realpath("/home/wazilly/public_html/recipe.json") ); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); $headers = array(); $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json"; curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); $result = curl_exec($ch); if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); } curl_close ($ch);